# Print included types location

Tags: c++, c++11, types, include

I have a "big" C++ project where classes inherit from several classes...

In one class I have:

```
std::atomic<bool> myVariable;
```

And the compilation is ok and it works properly, **but** this file doesn't `#include <atomic>` .

Is there a way of printing which class or file actually included `atomic`?

I know I could search for it using the IDE's tools or even `grep` on the project. But I'm wondering if it can be done inside the program.

Comment: No doubt one or other of your required system headers includes the `<atomic>` file. But you should be explicitly including it yourself, if you use the `std::atomic` class template. That way, you would know for sure where it is included.

Comment: Not really. You could run preprocessor only (`-E` in gcc), but then you will get full code of every `#include` through which you would have to waddle. That's why all coding guidelines say "include what you use, don't rely on other includes".

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection.  This isn't something you can do with the language as is.

Comment: does it matter what file actually included it? If that one class is using it then it should include it. Note that unittesting is a way to catch such missing includes rather reliably.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thank you, I'm aware I should add the include :) I 'm just curious

Comment: Just to show how unwieldy task it is, only `#include <iostream>` gives you 23 thousand lines after preprocessor is done: https://godbolt.org/z/hbxxre9EY (but it doesn't include atomic it seems). I was hoping that you could see file boundaries with include guards, but I forgot this is preprocessor too, so no luck. I don't know of any other way to see what includes what except for looking at source code directly.

Comment: Are you looking for `gcc -H`?